# VirtualBox: "USB Device Is Being In Use By Someone Else" error. How to let the guest OS grab it without crashing my Mac?

Tags: linux, macos, usb, virtualbox, osx-el-capitan

First of all, I want to make clear that I have read [this question:

VirtualBox: "USB device in use by someone else" error, how to make (mac) host let go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14689354/3960947)

However, although I do everything that the answers say and try to make the Guest OS grab the USB device, my Mac crashes and freezes. Then I have to restart, and a message appears in the boot screen that my Mac was shut down because of a problem.

- Host OS = Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)
- Guest OS = Ubuntu 16.04
- USB Device = USB Adapter: TP-Link Archer T2UH (AC600)